# Lenovo not allowing to create folder in sd card

Tags: android, directory

I'm trying to create a folder in android sd card...For that I've added permission in manifest file and My this is my code..

```
public void createFile(View view)
    {
        String state= Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
            File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");
            res=wallpaperDirectory.mkdir()
            if(res){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Make sure that you have a memory card mounted...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

When I ran the same code in kitkat emulator its creating folder but Its always saying failed in lenovo...Thanks in advance...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="bk.acs">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SubActivity1"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: do you have sd card in your device

Comment: Yes I have ..If I dont have sd card then it should give toast as Make sure blah blah..

Comment: can show your menifest and please tell your os version

Comment: I'm testing in nougat bro ..I updated manifest please see it

Comment: @bharath see what I said in my answer below. Since you are testing it in nougat, You must request permission at run time. It will not work otherwise

Comment: ok bro I will add and see thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are NOT suppose to hard code file paths in Android. `/sdcard/` doesn't work for all Android devices.

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead.

Here's how:

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Wallpaper");
    if(!wallpaperDirectory.exist()) {
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdir();
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, if you are testing on 6.0+ Android version, just declaring permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` is not enough. You need to [request permission during run time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request).  That is another reason why it might be working KitKat but not on newer Android versions.

Comment: bro I'm successful in creating directory but it is not visible from my computer..How to make it public ?